# Change a label over a time increment

Tags: vb.net, label, thread-sleep

I am trying to make a label that changes every second for an event. What I currently have makes the thread sleep all the way through from "Rock" to "Shoot" and skips the "Paper" and "Scissors". Does anyone have any ideas as to what I should do to properly display the label so that they are all displayed in equal time increments? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
lblCountdown.Text = "Rock"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
lblCountdown.Text = "Paper"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
lblCountdown.Text = "Scissors"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
lblCountdown.Text = "Shoot!"
```

Comment: @KenWhite: `Invalidate()` posts a message onto the queue; it doesn't redraw immediately.  And the `Text` setter calls it for you.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for the clarification. :) I'll delete both my prior comments. (As I said, I'm not a VB.NET developer, and I wouldn't be doing anything like this myself. I typically use threads to do the work, and the threads post messages to the UI thread to update status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling it from the UI thread, the rendering will lock up until the code is finished, so you won't see Paper or Scissors. One solution (not the *best* solution, but *a* solution) is to call `Me.Refresh()` or `Application.DoEvents()` before each `Sleep`. This will tell the UI to redraw itself.

A better solution would be to use some kind of timer that ticks at a 1 second interval, which would operate in another thread, freeing up your UI thread for more important things.

Answer (score 0):

Timer and Invoking would be a good way to handle this:

```
Private WithEvents m_tmrGame As New System.Timers.Timer(1000)
Private m_intShouldBeAnEnum As Integer = 1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    m_tmrGame.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub m_tmrGame_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles m_tmrGame.Elapsed

    Dim strCurrentObject As String = String.Empty

    Select Case m_intShouldBeAnEnum
        Case 1
            strCurrentObject = "Rock"
            m_intShouldBeAnEnum = 2
        Case 2
            strCurrentObject = "Paper"
            m_intShouldBeAnEnum = 3
        Case 3
            strCurrentObject = "Scissors"
            m_intShouldBeAnEnum = 4
        Case 4
            strCurrentObject = "Shoot!"
            m_intShouldBeAnEnum = 1
            m_tmrGame.Stop()
    End Select

    lblCountdown.Invoke(Sub(lblTarget As Label) lblTarget.Text = strCurrentObject, New Object() {lblCountdown})

End Sub
```